# Adding a hook upon update in mercurial (hg)

Tags: mercurial, hook, updates

I am currently working on a project which is under `mercurial` control and I was looking to get a hook upon update to edit the `.htaccess` fille to avoid changing the `APPLICATION_ENV` to fit the "mode" the application should run/load configs/connect to the database.

My repository structure goes as follow :

```
Main dev repo (ENV : development)
    +-- Stable repo (Production version) (ENV : production)
    +-- Local dev repo (working version) (ENV : development)
        +-- Prototype repo (prototyping repo) (ENV : prototype)
```

The part of the `.htaccess` I would like to have edited is the following (the first to lines of the file) :

```
# Application var
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

I don't mind to run a `python` script ( or any other language) I am looking to the right hook to put in the `.hg\hgrc` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right thing to do, since that would change the actual file. The next commit you make you would actually commit that change to your repository.

Instead, the recommended approach is to do the following:

1. Make a template file, and commit that to your repository, ie. `.htaccess.template`
2. Add the actual file, `.htaccess` to the `.hgignore` file to make Mercurial avoid it
3. Locally, make a copy from the template file to the actual file, and then edit that

This ensures that changes to the actual file, whatever they may be, will not be committed to your repository.

Some configuration systems also support conditional includes, so that you can something like `if extra config file X exists, load X as well`, and you would then do the following instead:

1. Commit the actual file to the repository, but make it bare-bones, containing default values
2. End the file with such an include-statement
3. Add the name of the file you're including to the `.hgignore` file so that you won't commit such a file to the repository

This would ensure that anyone can add to or override the default configuration by adding their own version of that file that will be included.